# Edit parameters and typehints for a class method

Tags: python, python-inspect

I have a class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
        pass
```

As you see, this code will display args & kwargs for typehints. But, I want to inspect method and change it's arguments and typehints using inspect.Signature, and I have a dict with all field names and their typehints:

```
{param: Optional[str] # as an example}
```

So, how do I change those parameter names & their typehints?

Comment: Unless the only thing you do with `*args` and `kwargs` is pass them to another function, it would be better to spell out the parameters explicitly in the signature. (And if that *is* all you do with them, I would prefer clean code to overly complicated code that tries to make up for the shortcomings of any particular editor or IDE.)

Comment: I have to make subclasses of this class

Comment: I found Signature.replace, but I am not able to update class method's annotations